# Angular Reactive Form custom input simple implementation

Tags: angular, forms

I have a REALLY simple FormGroup, 3 text inputs, one of them is supposed to be JSON (I wrote the custom validator for it) and I want to make the form to get an array instead of the json string

I would like to make the JSON input in another component while still maintaining the same form, but the form should receive the already parsed json (which should be an array) instead of the string, before validation applies, because otherwise I'd have to parse it for every validation and even for further usage which is very consuming
I know I should use ControValueAccessor but I just can't understand how to do that

(JsonValidator checks if it's a json string, ShapeValidator checks if its an array and if the objects inside it have a certain shape, both have to parse the json)

```js
public form = new FormGroup({
    jsonGraphData: new FormControl('', [JsonValidator, JsonShapeValidator]),
    xAxis: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    yAxis: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
```

what I would like to have

```js
public form = new FormGroup({
    jsonGraphData: new FormControl('', ArrayShapeValidator),
    xAxis: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    yAxis: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
```

and in the template use something like

```html
<custom-textarea formControlName="jsonGraphData"></custom-textarea>
```

tl;dr: custom input component should transform a text input in a parsed json before validation, and if it cant transform the text just return an empty array

Comment: you want validation or transformation ?

Comment: transformation from jsonString to Object/Array before validation is applied

TL;DR: THIS TRANSFORMATION

try {
return JSON.parse(value)
catch(e) {
return []
}

Comment: @bubbles I made a little confusion with the message above, if you are already reading reload the page, now it's correct :  )